# Salesforce lightning inspector chrome extension not found

Tags: lightning-aura-components, debugging, javascript-debugging

Tried to install Google chrome extension Salesforce Lightning Inspector but it takes me to 404 page which means that there is no extension literally not available to install. Is there a way to get this? Does Salesforce released some other tools for debugging? But according to the documentation it seems like the extension still exists.

**please don't close this question if you don't know the answer or if don't know Salesforce just leave it as it is. Someone who knows the platform very well can answer.**

[Salesforce Lightning Inspector](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/inspector_intro.htm)

Any thoughts?

[image]

Comment: I asked our lightning experts internally. Will keep you posted

Comment: @Bforce-  This is up now, you can try the same. 
Ref - https://twitter.com/ch_sz_knapp/status/1287633088542134274

Comment: @YsrShk thanks for letting me aware of this. I will take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extension is temporarily removed. There was an issue with permissions and a new version is published to resolve it, but it's still under review with Google. It will be back up soon

See this post on twitter: https://twitter.com/YsrShk/status/1276025491485388800

> **Update**
> This has been updated by Salesforce. Lightning Inspector is up now.
>
> Ref - https://twitter.com/YsrShk/status/1287697565153017856

Comment: Hi i have a question here, why people are urged to close the question because they dont know the answer for the question or the question is something off topic? If they dont know any solution i think better they can leave it as is so it can be answered by someone else. Kindly clarify. I saw three close votes which I am feeling as ridiculous and attitude of an insane